How can I concatenate vectors and/or exchange variable references in Pari/GP with less overhead?
I'm trying to improve the existing Pari/GP program for generating the elements of A060322. My code is much faster than the existing program, but a lot of stack and a fair amount of time is wasted with concatenating vectors and exchanging the contents of variables that refer to them. Is there a way to do this with less overhead?
A060322(N) = {
    my(a=Vec([1, 1, 1, 1, 2], N), p=[], q=[5]); 
    for(n=6, N, 
        r=concat([
                  [4*x+1 | x<-p],
                  [4*x\3 | x<-p, 1==x%6],
                  [2*x\3 | x<-q, 5==x%6]
                 ]);
        a[n]=a[n-1]+#r; 
        p=q; 
        q=r);
        a 
    }

So far my only thought is to use a three-element vector of vectors  instead of the three vectors (p,q,r), and reference each vector by a changing index rather than copy between them - but that's clumsy, and I would still have the problem of concatenation.
